# Multi Value from settings

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have question about MultiValue in AppSettings. I know how to obtain the chosen value but how to make a "if" with this values please?

Thank you

EDIT: Thanks, but I have a one question, I want to make it user friendly and want to easily change the choose in the app too. So I have to make table and save the values?

Comment: you want to change settings values by user entered then you can use text fields in a scroll view or table view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use if as -

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *str = [defaults stringForKey:@"Yourpreference"];
if (str) 
{
    if ([str isEqualToString:@""]) 
    {

    }
    else 
    {

    }
}
```